# Bezout's theorem on other surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $A$, $B$ are very ample curves on $\mathbb{P}^2$. Then I think you can show that $A^2 + B^2 > A.B$ with Bezout's theorem. How badly does this fail or hold on an arbitrary smooth surface? A bezout type argument doesn't seem to work in the same way since Pic has more dimensions in general. I feel like there must be a counterexample, but I am having trouble coming up with one... (I've tried, with no success, making counter-examples on the cubic surface, and on a few ruled surfaces where I know the intersection theory)

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thanks, let me try and do MathJax for the question

Comment: you can easily produce counter-examples on the quadric surface $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$. Take for instance $A$ be a type $(5,1)$ curve and $B$ a type $(1,5)$ curve on the surface.

Comment: Good thanks, I was actually just thinking if I could come up with something like A = L + 10f, B = L + 10g where f^2 = 0, g^2 = 0, but fg = 1 and L is ample (so like a ruled surface but with two sets of fibers... I don't know any examples, but probably something). In any case thanks for the example.